# Converting a size_t into an integer (c++)

Tags: c++, integer, size-t

I've been trying to make a for loop that will iterate based off of the length of a network packet. In the API there exists a variable (size_t) by event.packet->dataLength. I want to iterate from 0 to event.packet->dataLength - 7 increasing i by 10 each time it iterates but I am having a world of trouble.

I looked for solutions but have been unable to find anything useful. I tried converting the size_t to an unsigned int and doing the arithmetic with that but unfortunately it didn't work. Basically all I want is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < event.packet->dataLength - 7; i+=10) { }
```

Though every time I do something like this or attempt at my conversions the i < # part is a huge number. They gave a printf statement in a tutorial for the API which used "%u" to print the actual number however when I convert it to an unsigned int it is still incorrect. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Think about it:  What is the value of `static_cast<unsigned int>(-1)`?  What happens when `event.packet->dataLength` is less than 7?

Comment: Why can't `i` be a `size_t` too? Also, unless the length is always equal to 7 mod 10, this is a very peculiar loop to be attempting.

Comment: Did you try casting `event.packet->dataLength` to an `int`?

Comment: While we can fix the type inconsistencies, but we can't fix your logic until you [tell us the goal and your code](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @genpfault Wow I didn't even think that through, currently it's not working but most likely because it IS less than 7. I hate when I do stupid stuff.

Comment: @JeanOTF: The only reason *I* know about it is because I made the same mistake! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you change the type of `i`?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < event.packet->dataLength - 7; i+=10) { }
```

Try to keep the types of all variables used together the same type; casts should be avoided.

There is no format specifier for `size_t` in C++03, you have to cast to the largest unsigned integer type you can and print that. (The format specifier for `size_t` in C++0x is `%zu`). However, you shouldn't be using `printf` anyway:

```
std::cout << i; // print i, even if it's a size_t
```

While streams may be more verbose, they're more type safe and don't require you to memorize anything.

Keep in mind your actual loop logic may be flawed. (What happens, as genpfault notes, when `dataLength - 7` is negative?)

Comment: This won't help if `dataLength - 7` is negative, and I don't think it will do any good.

Comment: @David: No it won't, that's why I mentioned it. Hard to say what the fix is without knowing the intentions.

Comment: @Jean: What's "didn't work"? Can you show us your real code? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I think as someone mentioned above the value was in fact getting less than 0 which would make it go to a incredibly large number I real stupid mistake that I wasn't paying attention to. For some reason I was thinking that the value would never be less than 0 because of the indices.

Comment: How about `while (i + 7 < event.packet->dataLength)`?

Comment: -1 @Gman: your solution won't work. The OP stated that the subtraction "every time" results in a "huge number". Means typical packet size is less than 7, and as you note at the end, that's ungood.

Answer (score 2):

Do everything with signed arithmetic.  Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < int(event.packet->dataLength) - 7; i+=10) { }
```

Once you start using unsigned arithmetic with values that may be negative, and using comparison operators like `<`, you're in trouble.  Much easier to keep things signed.

Comment: Hm, I had to delete my original comment, thinking entirely too much in terms of standard-guaranteed behavior. On two's complement machine, with non-perverse compiler, i.e. *in practice*, the above will work. But that conversion of possibly huge unsigned value to `int` is formally UB. So, best fix the parenthesis. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach:  Thanks - even after your comment it took me a moment to realize what you meant, so it wasn't just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Is dataLength >= 7? If the result of dataLength-7 is negative, if you interpret it as unsigned, the result is a very large integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use size_t for i.

For printf, if you don't have C99, only C90, cast to unsigned long, or unsigned long long. E.g.:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        //printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)i);
        printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)i);
```

Otherwise use %zu

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if `event.packet->dataLength < 7`. Now if it's less then 7 you get values less than 0 used as unsigned: e.g. 0 = 0x00000000; -1 = 0 - 1 = 0xFFFFFFFF.

Again, the check:

```
if (event.packet->dataLength < 7) {
  ...
} else {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < event.packet->dataLength - 7; i+=10) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"every time I do something like this or attempt at my conversions the i < # part is a huge number."

That indicates that original packet length is less than 7 (you're subtracting 7).

One fix is to use an in-practice-large-enough signed integer type, and the standard library provides `ptrdiff_t` for that purpose. Like,

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // Not sure, but I think it was this one.

typedef ptrdiff_t    Size;
typedef Size         Index;

void foo()
{
    // ...
    for( Index i = 0; i < Size( event.packet->dataLength ) - 7; i += 10 )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

A more cumbersome workaround is to embed the whole thing in an `if` that checks that the size is at least 7.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Since `event.packet->dataLength` returns an unsigned type `size_t`:

1) Use `size_t` as the index variable type.

2) Insure math does not underflow.  [@beldaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686193/converting-a-size-t-into-an-integer-c/31119113#comment5168501_4686240).  Rather than subtract 7 from `event.packet->dataLength`, add 7 to `i`.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < event.packet->dataLength - 7; i+=10) { }
for (size_t i = 0; i + 7 < event.packet->dataLength; i += 10) { }
```